# How to set thread size of libuv in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, libuv

1. I have write a demo in nodejs like this:

hello.js:

```
var http = require(‘http’);
while(true){
    console.log(process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE);
}
```

2. I monitor the process and threads with 'pstree -p | grep node' after starting the program above.
3. I have tried 3 ways to edit thread size but none of them works:
   1) Set the paramters when starting: 'UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=100 node hello.js'
   2) add path in the etc/profile and reboot the system:export UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=100
   3) add 'process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=100' in the code.
4. the results of the monitor are the same:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vugfr.png)

There is only 5 threads work in the node process (4 are work threads and 1 is loop thread)

My nodejs is v6.9.x. Have anyone used this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE , as of this writing the max limit is 128.

If you want you can also set this env variable within your node app rather than at the shell.